# factorization of a block matrix under certain conditions

Tags: matrices

If $U=
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{s} & C_{s\times r} \\
B_{r\times s} & -I_{r} 
\end{pmatrix},$
then $U=
\begin{pmatrix}
I & -C \\
0 & I 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
I+CB & 0 \\
0 & I 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
I & 0 \\
B & -I 
\end{pmatrix}.$
How do I get this factorization? Is there a method?

Comment: This looks like a block matrix analog to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition

Comment: I'll try. If it works I'll type the answer.